# Como controlar el acceso o instalacion de un programa en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, seguridad

quisiera controlar la instalacion de un programa, osea solo permitir que se instale en los equipos que esten autorizados o en su defecto que se instale pero que al ejecutarlo los mande a un form vacio, pero no se si exista alguna forma en especifico para hacerlo, tenia la idea de hacerlo con la MAC, pero hay equipos con varias tarjetas de red que no se si seria un problema, hay algo mas que pueda ocupar como identificador unico por equipo, algo como los IMEI de los celulares

Comment: Autenticando contra un directorio activo, group policies? Lo que dices de los IMEI, tiene el gran lío de que no hay una red única que valide nada y si algo, uno monta una VM y pone la MAC manualmente, heh.

Comment: Si es en una PC donde se instalará tu programa, ¿no podrias usar el número de serie y el ID de la placa base?, se puede eliminar espacios en blancos y concatenar ambas cadenas o parte de ellas.